# Zen-Cart does not show product texts while editing a product

Tags: nginx, zen-cart

I'm running a small Zen-Cart shop and I have the following problem. When I'm in the administrator interface and edit a product, the name and description texts do not show. The text boxes are just empty for all languages. When I enter the name and description again all works fine and changes are saved and show up in the website.

I don't know if it has anything to do with this problem, but I'm running Zen-Cart on a NGINX webserver (on CentOS). PHP is supported through Fast-CGI. Except for this small problem the website runs fine and is fast.

I tried a copy of the website offline on a Windows machine (with WAMP) and here the problem does not occur. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although this is not a great solution:

The problem is in this line in collect_info.php:

```
<td class="main"><?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES . $languages[$i]['directory'] . '/images/' . $languages[$i]['image'], $languages[$i]['name']) . '&nbsp;' . zen_draw_input_field('products_name[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', (isset($products_name[$languages[$i]['id']]) ? htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($products_name[$languages[$i]['id']]), ENT_COMPAT, CHARSET, TRUE) : htmlspecialchars(zen_get_products_name($pInfo->products_id, $languages[$i]['id']), ENT_COMPAT, CHARSET, TRUE)), zen_set_field_length(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, 'products_name')); ?></td>
```

Using `$pInfo->products_name` instead of `$products_name[$languages[$i]['id']]` and `zen_get_products_name(...)` does work. This only works if you have only one language.

For description I can use the FCK Editor which was working here already.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part from all lines, it works: `, ENT_COMPAT, CHARSET, TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this problem before, but I would try these paths to locate the problem better:

1. Have you tried to select "no editor"? You can do this BEFORE you open the product page, on the listing of the category, at the top-right you have a menu "Text editor", select None or No editor and check if the problem still occurs.
2. Have you checked the zen error logs? In the newer versions of Zencart they are included and active by default, previous to version 1.3.9a you have to install the [error-logging function](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84613) to activate them. Then you can access the logs under /cache, or whatever your cache folder is.
3. Is it a problem occurring with products only? What about categories, customers, EZ-pages or other edits? If it is a problem of the products page only, I would try re-uploading the product.php file under your admin directory.

Comment: 1. Thank you for your suggestions. I do not have the option "no editor", but the editor was in setting "plain text". When I change this to FCK Editor (I have this installed). The description shows, but the product name not.

Comment: 3. Yes, products only. The problem does not happen with categories or any other sections as far as I noticed. Retransfer of product.php does not help.

Comment: Plain editor = no editor. It seems quite strange that the text shows when you select an editor, FCK in your case. It could point to a javascript error, although I can't really see how to be honest. If you disable javascript in your browser, can you see the texts? What about the html source, can you see the text there? I would try re-installing the FCK editor either way: http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=268

Comment: With those details in mind, I think this has to be a FCK editor problem. Re-installing it should solve it if this is the case (and cleaning your browser cache afterward).

Comment: I first uninstalled the FCK editor, cleared the browser cache and still the problem continues. Next I installed the lasted version of FCK editor, cleared the cache. The problem continues. Disabling JavaScript does not change anything either. I checked the HTML source and with the "Plain Text" editor the values of name and description are simply not there. With FCK editor the value of description is there.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Are you using linked products in your catalog? Have you copied a product from another product?

Are all fields empty when you are viewing your product information in the editor screen?

It may be the master categories id is not configured correctly, and therefore it is not populating your admin product form correctly.

The FCK Editor does not effect the populating of the product name or pricing fields. Therefore, it may be attributed to an incorrect master category id.